# Display image and text inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble getting an image on each side of a heading. I've tried display:inline-block but that's not doing it for me.
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uyjmffbu/)

```
.inline-image{display:inline-block}
```

The imgur pictures may not be showing up but you get the idea.
It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Details: Using Bootstrap v3.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `display: inline-block` to the actual element(s) not the parent:

```
.inline-image img, .inline-image h3{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Then you can adjust the `vertical-align` property to `middle`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uyjmffbu/3/)