# Display <img> and <p> in-line

Tags: html

I would like my image to come right after my `<p>` tag in the same line. I tried to wrap them inside a `<div>` block with `display:inline-block` set but to no avail.

```
<div style="float:left; display:inline-block; ">
  <span style="float:left;width: 50%;">
    <p style="float:left; display:block;" class="sentiment">Sentiment</p>
  </span>
  <span style="float:right;width: 50%;">
    <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google.a51985becaa6.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;">
  </span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BMv5u/59/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display image and text inline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932557/display-image-and-text-inline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding inline-block to each of the sub elements:

```
<div>
  <p style="display:inline-block;" class="sentiment">Sentiment</p>
  <img style="width:20px;height:20px;display:inline-block" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google.a51985becaa6.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `align` property on the img. check the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BMv5u/75/)

```
<p >
  <img  src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google.a51985becaa6.png" ALIGN="right" alt="">
    Sentiment  
</p>
```